# Why can't I arrange layers in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I'm working on a design with layered text. I want to have a word on top of another and when I select the layer and go to `arrange > bring to front` it won't do it. I've tried sending the rest of the layers to the back but the design stays as if I've done nothing. I am not sure if it's a **settings** thing or if i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Illustrator layers are *not* like Photoshop layers.

Illustrator has two types of stacks. The **Object Stack** and the **Layer Stack**.

**Each layer has an independent, self-contained, object stack.** The object stack is localized to *that* layer *only*. Meaning, each layer has its own independent stack of objects contained on that layer which does not reference any other layer. This controls what is on top of what for that layer and *only* that layer.

The `Bring to Front/Back` commands control the **object stack** *not* the layer stack. Therefore `Bring to Front/Back` will **never** move objects *between* layers. Whenever you use `Bring To Front/Back` you are merely rearranging objects on *one* layer, **never** more than one layer.

If you wish to alter the **layer stack**, rather than the object stack, you **must** click and drag layers in the **Layer Panel**. This must also be done to move objects *between* layers - although for *objects*, it's also possible to copy/paste to move them between layers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem even though I was only using one layer. No response at all.

The solution was to exit Isolation mode. Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. 
You can see in your Layers panel if its activated or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The answers i found did not give me the results i needed. so i played around with the menus and found.. to move the layers after most likely using the "move to back", "Move forward" etc. commands. You need to select the layer in the layers tab the "shift+click" the layer you want to move it to. Then right click, arrange, "send to current layer". Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This actually moves **objects** between layers. Which may be fine, but it's not the same as reordering layers themselves.

Comment: Seems to me @Scott that this is a modeling error on the users part. They are trying to replucate how they use layers in photoshop etc. But in illustrator you really want to have less layers you only want main level layers once you have decided that this stuff really needs to be on top and under. Then keep majority of your objecs in one layer. So in essence you want to use object the way you use layers in photoshop. I have however considered that a hypothetical, perfect vector application would separate organisation tree from drawing tree, altgough messy it could solve advanced logic issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer to the original question, but if you want to change the order of the layers themselves (rather than objects within layers), then you need to drag them into the desired order in the layer window. The layer at the top appears in front of the subsequent layers. (This is the answer I was looking for so thanks for helping me work it out!)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with a text and an image. What I found out was that my image wasn't even selectable due to the fact that I needed to relink it on the "Links" tab.

Hope I could help someone!